# press y to continue, any other key to exit (Shell script)

Tags: shell, unix

I've written below code, but it won't work for SPACE,special symbols etc.
I want my script to exit if any key pressed on keyboard apart from Y/y.
It should handle SPACEBAR,special symbols

```
echo "enter y, any other key to exit "
read input
if [ $input != "Y" -o $input  = "y" ]; then
echo "Exiting"
fi

if [ $input == "Y" -o $input == "y" ]; then
echo "Working"
fi
```

Comment: First: should be `if [ $input != "Y" -o $input  != "y" ];`

Comment: my bad it is actually if [ $input != "Y" -o $input  != "y" ];

Answer (score 3):

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read?s[]=read

Normally you always want to use the -r flag. -n 1 tells read to only read 1 character.

```
asksure() {
echo -n "Are you sure (Y/N)? "
while read -r -n 1 -s answer; do
  if [[ $answer = [YyNn] ]]; then
    [[ $answer = [Yy] ]] && retval=0
    [[ $answer = [Nn] ]] && retval=1
    break
  fi
done

echo # just a final linefeed, optics...

return $retval
}

### using it
if asksure; then
  echo "Okay, performing rm -rf / then, master...."
else
  echo "Pfff..."
fi
```

Comment: I got one solution........ 
if [[ $input != "Y" && $input  = "y" ]]; then
echo "Exiting"
exit
fi

Comment: in bash, the right-hand side of `==` is a pattern, so you can do `if [[ $input == Y|y ]]; then ...`

Comment: I believe tat depends on the version of bash.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to quote the parameter expansions to make sure certain inputs are not removed altogether during word splitting and quote removal.

You are using the wrong operator. No matter what key you type, one of `not Y` and `not y` will be true. For example, `"Y" != "y"`. You want to use `and` instead of `or`.

```
if [ "$input" != "Y" ] && [ "$input" != "y" ]; then
```

The boolean operators `-o` and `-a` are no longer recommended, due to ambiguities than can arise from their use. Use separate `test` commands joined by `||` and `&&` (respectively) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put $input in quotes, so the statement parses properly.  If your response is a space, what the script sees is

```
if [  != "Y" -o != "y" ]; then
```

Which it obviously can't parse properly.

Use

```
if [ "$input" != "Y" -o "$input"  = "y" ]; then
```

and you should be OK.

By the way, you don't actually exit if the condition is met.  Add a `return` after the `echo "Exiting"` line.

Comment: As an aside, `-o` is all but deprecated; recommended usage is `if [ "$input" = "Y" ] || [ "$input" != "y" ]; then` instead.